# Trying to get response from web-service using JSON error occurs

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to get response from web-service using JSON but following error occurs.

[image: JSON Error]

Please help me to solve it

Comment: Why use commented out catch section?

Comment: @Poles I tried different options. But it should work without catch

Comment: As it says in the console on your image: `JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set`. So...what does your JSON look like? Is it valid JSON (try checking it in jsonlint.com for instance). And if you need to allow fragments you can read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization.readingoptions

Comment: *... but it should work without catch* - **Never** assume that there is no need to handle errors when loading data over the internet.

Comment: I found out what the mistake was, and it's very strange.
after this line

defaults.set(nil, forKey: "user")
defaults object under key "user" have 135 byte and I don't understand why

Comment: because you have to call the synchronize on the userDefaults object you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that the JSON returned from the web is not correctly formatted. I would suggest to extract data in a string in order to check what you are receiving with the debugger.

I noticed in the setter that you are setting the UserDefaults but without synchronize. After a change of the defaults object you need to call `defaults.synchronize()` in order to make effective your changes.

At last I would suggest to never assume that the data coming from the web are correct and I would recommend to put the try in a do catch so that the user will not have a crash in case of problems.

Hope it helped.

Comment: `After a change of the defaults object you need to call defaults.synchronize() in order to make effective your changes.` No you don't, not anymore (it's been the case for a few OS versions now). Default is automatically synchronized by the system. Calling `.synchronize()` manually is only necessary in very rare cases that I have yet to encounter on SO.

Comment: From apple Documentation: The synchronize() method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

You have no warranty on WHEN the synchronize is called. Soon or later it will, but if you are consulting user defaults for the property you changed  one instant ago, you might find the old value.

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying. Funny how every time I bring this matter, someone shows me the same documentation snippet - which is exactly saying what I'm saying. ;) Defaults `is automatically invoked at periodic intervals`. You only need synchronize() when `you are consulting user defaults for the property you changed one instant ago` which is rare *and* has a workaround: look at the object you were saving instead of looking at it once saved. In real apps, you almost *never* need synchronize(), and OP certainly doesn't need it here.

Comment: I prefere to not work using entropic pattern, saying "it **almost** never happen". in this case it's very possible that it happens: login -> setUser -> getUserPrefUsingTheUser. As you can see the getter fetch from UserDefaults. In this scenario you set the user and you use it immediately after. I'm not saying that it is a good practice, I'm saying that it is possible. A synchronize does not hurt.

Comment: And again, "periodically" does not specify the frequency. you have no warranty that one second after the change you will find the new value. It is a good practice to run the synchronize if you want to be sure that the next time you will ask for the key you will find the new value.

Comment: `A synchronize does not hurt.` That's where we disagree, I suppose. :) Calling synchronize when not needed *can* definitely be hurtful - if the defaults have lots of data (as some iOS devs like to do) the plist will take time to be synchronized, and this is done on the main thread, so it may cause lag. // *And* having to check what has been saved the instant before is an anti-pattern. But this is a matter of opinion, I guess.

Comment: As I said I'm not saying it is a good way to go. I'm just saying that it is possible. If your app rely on userDefaults for an important task, then you must be damn sure of the consistency of your data. It's a mistake, it's a terrible decision, but still, if you want to be 100% sure that your data are consistent you have 2 choices: wait a reasonable amount of time to user the userDefaults again so that you are sure iOS did the synchronize, or synchronize explicitly.